# How to scroll parent ScrollView while child is moving in it using PanResponder

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, panresponder

I am looking for an option to build this functionality in react native.

[image]

I have added  PanResponder inside a scroll view but the problem is when I drag an item in screen scroll view does not scroll. So is there any option available in react-native to drag and scroll at the same time to achieve the same view.

Comment: I also had a similar problem. But ended up cloning the picked item, rendering it outside the scroll view and handled pan separately for it. When you pick up an item we use scrollTo() from ScrollView. On pan release, you change the original item and discard the cloned one.